I want this to make an error message if the user isn't using the right format, but it just displays this
It just displays this instead of the error warning I made:

Here is how I want it to be:

And here is my code:
Console.Write("Masukkan Tinggi Segitiga: ");
int tinggi = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (tinggi > 0)
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= tinggi; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
else if (tinggi <= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input tidak valid! Harus berupa angka & bilangan bulat");
}


Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); <-- Don't do this. Use Int32.TryParse instead.

The reason why it throws an exception is that you passed in an invalid number string and try to parse it. (i.e. "a" is not a number.)
Using int.TryParse() and use the returned value to control your condition to output the error message you want:
Console.WriteLine("=====TP MODUL 3=====");
Console.Write("Masukkan Tinggi Segitiga: ");
var parseResult = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var tinggi);

if (!parseResult || tinggi <= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input tidak valid! Harus berupa angka & bilangan bulat");
}
else
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= tinggi; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

Output:
=====TP MODUL 3=====
Masukkan Tinggi Segitiga: a
Input tidak valid! Harus berupa angka & bilangan bulat


@aaallc How it works? If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

you could try:
if (int.TryParse(input, out tinggi))
{
    ...code here
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("something in that language");
}

